# Doubt on 'Rest Theorem' in Polynomial Division

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm dealing with an issue dividing polynomials, I have:

Determine the value of $a$ to make: $x^2 + 2x - a$ divisible by $x + 4$

I don't know even where to start, this $a$ confuses me a lot;

Thanks in advance;

But I'm still confused, I'm trying to divide it in the longer way, I've multiplied with an $x$ coefficient and got a rest of $-2x - a$ but I'm unable to find the other part of the coefficient to cancel that $-2x$ and got the $a$.

Comment: Have you ever seen something called "the factor theorem"? That would be an excellent place to start.

Comment: Are you familiar with polynomial long division?

Comment: Multiply $x+4$ with $x-\frac{a}{4}$ and compare coefficients.

Comment: @anon yes, my difficult is there, take a look in my edit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gerry's comment will lead you to consider something like this: If $x+4$ really does divide $x^2+2x-a$, then $$x^2+2x-a=(x+4)(x+c)$$ for some $c$ that we don't really know or care about. What happens if you plug in $x=-4$?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use the fact that $-4$ is a root of the polynomial $P(x)$ iff $x+4$ divides $P(x)$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\rm\:x\!+\!4\ |\ f(x)\:$ then $\rm\:mod\ x\!+\!4\!:\ 0 \equiv f(x)\equiv f(-4)\: $ by $\rm\: x\equiv -4.$

Alternatively in divisibility (vs. congruence form), apply the [Factor Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem)

Or, by [Vieta,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) if the roots are $\rm\:r,-4\:$ then their sum is minus the linear coefficient $\rm\: r\!-\!4 = -2,\:$ hence $\rm\: r = 2,\:$ and the root product is the constant coefficient $\rm\: -4\:\!r = -a\:\Rightarrow\: a =\: \ldots$

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+2x−a$  is the standard form.

\begin{align}
(x+4)(x+c) &= x^2+2x-a\\
x^2+cx+4x+4c &= x^2+2x-a
\end{align}

mean

$$x^2+(c+4)x+4c = x^2+2x-a$$
\begin{align}
c+4 &= 2 & 4c &= -a\\
c &=-2 & 4(-2) &= -a\\
-a &= -8 & a &= 8
\end{align}

so $x^2+2x-8$,  where the value of $a$ is $8$.

Answer (score 0):

P(-4)=0

Then:
 $$(-4)^2+2\cdot{(-4)}-a  = 0$$
$$16-8-a  = 0$$
$$8  = a$$